# Why is the MYSQL variable innodb_file_per_table changed to OFF automatically in a OPENSHIFT online gear?

Tags: mysql, mysql5.5, openshift-online-2

My application is on openshift online gear with mySQL 5.5. Recently I found that my mySQL database become very big quickly (few days increase 1G) without many operations. This made me try to do optimize database. To my surprise, every time I optimize the database, the size of db (increase 1G). /mysql/ibdata1 is huge.

After investigation, I surprisingly discovered that Innodb_file_per_table is OFF. To me it is very strange and my install and deploy scripts all set it to ON (from the beginning). I also tried manually set it ON. However, after 1 day, it was changed to OFF again. Does anyone know why? Or Anyway to know the reason. Thanks.

Comment: Whoever created the gear set that up. You can always create a custom gear based on that one.

Answer (score 0):

I found when the gear restart, it changed to OFF. It seems that openshift does not run post_start_php when re-starting the gear. I need to add post_restart script to set innodb_file_per_table ON. Now it seems OK.

Comment: Remember to dump and reload your DB to actually have your DB use a different file per table.